# Pasar SelectedValue de ComboBox hacia otro Form

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, .net, visual-studio-2015, combobox

Buen dia Estimados, tengo 2 formularios muy sencillos, en 1 tengo un combobox con 1 boton y en el otro un dgv que se llena mediante una consulta sql. Mi problema es que en el form que tengo el combobox selecciono el id de la sucursal y ese ahi lo tengo que pasar hacia el otro formulario para meterlo adentro de la consulta sql y que solo me arroje resultados de la sucursal que fue seleccionada. Les adjunto los codigos con los que estoy trabajando ya que el valor esta pasando null hacia el otro form. Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Form con boton y combobox

```
Imports DataAccess
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class SeleccionBase
    Public Property IdSuc As Integer
    Private Sub SeleccionBase_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.cbCampana.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        Try
            Dim msCadenaSQL As String = "Data Source=MASTER;Initial Catalog=PRINCIPAL;Integrated Security=True"
            ' Configuramos una conexión con el origen de datos.
            Using loConexion As New SqlConnection(msCadenaSQL)
                ' crear adaptadores
                Dim lDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from sucursales", loConexion)
                Dim lDataTable As New DataTable
                lDataAdapter.Fill(lDataTable)
                'Cargar el combo
                With cbCampana
                    .DisplayMember = "NOMBRE_SUCURSAL"
                    .ValueMember = "ID_SUC"
                    .DataSource = lDataTable
                    .SelectedIndex = -1
                End With
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
  
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Using loForm As New prueba
            loForm.Padre = Me
            loForm.ShowDialog()
        End Using

        cbCampana.SelectedValue = IdSuc

    End Sub

End Class
```

Form con Datagrid

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class prueba
    Public Property Padre As SeleccionBase

    Private Sub prueba_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim msCadenaSQL As String = "Data Source=BARNEY;Initial Catalog=CT;Integrated Security=True"
            ' Configuramos una conexión con el origen de datos.
            Using loConexion As New SqlConnection(msCadenaSQL)
                ' crear adaptadores
                Dim lDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CTES WHERE ID_SUC=" + Padre.IdUsuario.ToString + "", loConexion)
                Dim lDataTable As New DataTable
                lDataAdapter.Fill(lDataTable)
                Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = lDataTable

            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Bueno desde ya les agradezco mucho la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a crear una propiedad pública en Prueba de tipo string donde pasas ese valor y luego en el formulario SeleccionBase haces la llamada a esa propiedad, junto con el formulario. Te pongo un ejemplo sobre tu código:
Form con Datagrid

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class prueba
    Public Property Padre As SeleccionBase
    'Esta variable podrás pasar el valor que necesitas.
    Private Dim Sucursal As String 
    Public WriteOnly Property IdSucursal() As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Sucursal = value
            
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub prueba_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
        Dim msCadenaSQL As String = "Data Source=BARNEY;Initial Catalog=CT;Integrated Security=True"
        ' Configuramos una conexión con el origen de datos.
        Using loConexion As New SqlConnection(msCadenaSQL)
            ' crear adaptadores
            Dim lDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CTES WHERE ID_SUC=" + Sucursal + "", loConexion)
            Dim lDataTable As New DataTable
            lDataAdapter.Fill(lDataTable)
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = lDataTable

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Y en el formulario del combobox en el evento click

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    
            Using loForm As New prueba
                'Aqui pasamos el valor para cuando lo mostremos ya tenga el valor.
                loForm.IdSucursal = cbCampana.SelectedValue
                loForm.Padre = Me
                loForm.ShowDialog()

            End Using
                    
    End Sub
```

Espero haber entendido la pregunta y que te sirva. Si me permites la sugerencia yo utilizaría pasar parámetros en vez de concatenar cadenas. Cuando te acostumbras puede ser hasta más fácil entenderlo. Puedes mirar: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Edito: Revisa lo que he puesto, porque ya suelo escribir en c# y vb lo he dejado un poco de lado. Pero la idea es esa.

Comment: Hola Gines, si ahi lo pase por parametro con el sqlcomand, y lo pude levantar de ahi con eso que me pasaste. Ahora te consulto, con eso puedo pasar tambien un datareader que contiene informacion? o no me serviria para hacer eso.

Comment: En principio si podrías crear otra propiedad pero esta vez en vez de ser string tendría que ser datareader.

Comment: Private Dim rd As DataReader  
Public Property Datos() As DataReader
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            rd = value
            
End Get

Con esa propiedad nueva y tendría que funcionar. Depende de la cantidad de datos lo mismo ya tienes que complicar un poco más y tienes que añadir algún hilo o una pantalla de espera. Pero tendrían que ser muchos datos.

Comment: Gines, encontre una manera que tiene el visual studio que es guardar los datos en una variable global declarada en el proyecto. Esa variable la podes llamar desde cualquier formulario e ir actualizandola. Te agradezco mucho por tu ayuda igualmente. Saludos